# Trying to display the velocity of a GameObject in Unity, numbers bouncing all over

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok I'm developing a game in which you land a rocket ship while avoiding asteroids...  Pretty simple.  I have two UI Text elements that are meant to display the current vertical and horizontal velocity.  I searched around and came up empty in terms of unity having a built in function to get the current velocity of a 2D rigidbody so I came up with this:

```
void Update () {

    shipVelocity = Mathf.Abs((lastPosition.y - spaceShip.transform.position.y) / Time.deltaTime);
    shipAngularVelocity = Mathf.Abs((lastPosition.x - spaceShip.transform.position.x) / Time.deltaTime);
    uiText = "Vertical Velocity: " + shipVelocity;
    currentVelocityText.text = uiText;
    uiText = "Horizontal Velocity: " + shipAngularVelocity;
    currentAngularVelocityText.text = uiText;

    lastPosition = spaceShip.transform.position;
}
```

Basically it just does your standard velocity = delta position / delta time but something is wrong.  The numbers bounce all over the place and after the ship has landed and is completely stationary the numbers still bounce around from 0-1.  While it's flying the numbers rapidly change from what I think is an accurate velocity to 0 and back - so fast it basically just looks like it's blinking.

Could it be it's just calling it too fast?  I.e. frame rate too high? If so how can I slow it down?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating a Rigidbody, it is important to put your update logic in "FixedUpdate()". This version of update is called at a set rate (default 50x/sec) and therefore should be used for updating physics logic. Link: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

This is common in games as it separates the framerate (draws/sec) from the update logic (updates/sec), meaning that of the framerate drops, the games underlying physics are not altered.

Comment: It might be worth looking into the value Time.FixedDeltaTime https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html